# Eclipse: create two projects sharing files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, sharing

I need to create an application that will be deployed on Desktop and Android.
I'll use the MVC pattern; the Desktop and Android versions will share the Controller and the Model.

I thus want to create my two projects in a way that allows me to share the code related to the controller and the model, each project having its own version of the view.

What is the best way to do that in Eclipse? I don't want to use the code as a library because it must be possible to modify it directly from any of the two projects, with the modifications visible immediately in both.

Moreover, when the applications will be done, I must be able to generate an "ant build file", so I want a file structure that allows to build the two versions separately with no redundancy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share class files and jar files between projects as a library, so what you would need would be three projects: two with the interface code and one with the common files.  The common files would be your library.

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the common files directly from the two "interface" projects ? And what about ant ? By the way, thanks!

Comment: Yes.  I'm actually doing this now.  I have one lib that is shared with several apps.  You 'link' the app/lib with the app properties.  You add the jar under the lib/bin directory to the app/properties/build I think, make sure it's marked for export in the properties and link the directory.  Things in the build sometimes get 'confused' so after you change the library, do a 'clean' on both the lib and app to synch things.

Comment: WhaT worked best for me was to start with one project and then create the lib and move common code to it.  Start simple...

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use maven or gradle build https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven-android/